# how to query files from a course of which a student is a part?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

On the profile page of user I want to display the files of the course of which he is part of.
Here is the code in flask and flask_sqlalchemy I have written in my models.py

I have got below code working but it is not efficient as you can see.

```py
files = []
for i in User.query.get(1).course:
    files.extend(i.files)
```

I want to do something like below which isn't working for some reasons.

```
>>> db.session.query(File).join(course_files).join(course_students).all()

Traceback Exception (most recent call):
#
```

Complete source code with relations.

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    mobile = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)


course_students = db.Table(
    'course_students',
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

course_files = db.Table(
    'course_files',
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.id')),
    db.Column('file_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('file.id'))
)


class Course(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    fees = db.Column(db.String)
    timing = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False)
    students = db.relationship('User', secondary=course_students,
                               backref=db.backref('course', lazy='dynamic'))
    files = db.relationship('File', secondary=course_files,
                            backref=db.backref('course', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Course({self.name})>'


class File(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    length = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    mime_type = db.Column(db.String, default='application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without the Exception details, but you might just be missing some instruction in the join that filters the query by the current user.

If the user you are viewing is in variable 'u' then a query like this would only return the relevant files for that user.

```
db.session.query(File).join(course_files).join(course_students, course_students.c.user_id == u.id).all()
```